# Visual Studio Code - display project name first on Alt+Tab window

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Following little issue:

My ustal workflow consist of several VS Code windows opened

When switching between them via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, Windows 10/11 displays their instances name in format `file_name - project_name`. Names might get capped as well, so usually I'm ending in format like `file_n...`. It's kinda annoying to guess, what from list like:

- `index...`
- `index.js - pr...`
- `index...`
  is the one, that I'm searching for.

The question: Is there a way to change display format of VS Code windows in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> view, preferably to show project name first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting [`window.title`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings) contains the file location first.

Change it to:

```
"window.title": "${rootName}${separator}${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${appName}"
```

Comment: You can the "window.title" attribute in your .vscode/settings.json for a specific workspace or globaly change the setting for all projects in vscode user settings (ctrl+,).

Comment: @Mountain that applies to almost all settings (depends on the scope of the setting in package.json)